Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory with Quarkus application
I'm trying to run my Quarkus application with usage of Oracle DB. When I start it I get PersistenceException that Hibernate cannot build SessionFactory.
Here is a stacktrace:
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
__  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______ 
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/
2024-08-20 14:02:41,812 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Attempting to start live reload endpoint to recover from previous Quarkus startup failure

2024-08-20 14:02:41,810 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile [dev]): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)                                                                                                                                      
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)                                                                                                                                     
        at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:111)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:71)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
        at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: <default>] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig.startAll(JPAConfig.java:78)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.HibernateOrmRecorder.startAllPersistenceUnits(HibernateOrmRecorder.java:101)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits1868654632.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits1868654632.deploy(Unknown Source)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: <default>] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.persistenceException(FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:126)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.build(FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:86)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.java:74)
        at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
        at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$LazyPersistenceUnit.get(JPAConfig.java:156)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$1.run(JPAConfig.java:64)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EmbeddableValuedModelPart.getNavigableRole()" because "mappingModelPart" is null
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.lambda$registerEmbeddableMappingType$1(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:229)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.visitRegisteredComponents(MetadataImpl.java:561)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.recording.PrevalidatedQuarkusMetadata.visitRegisteredComponents(PrevalidatedQuarkusMetadata.java:290)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.registerEmbeddableMappingType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:225)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:321)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:271)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.build(FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:84)
        ... 6 more



These are my properties for db :
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=oracle
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/ORCL
quarkus.datasource.username=username
quarkus.datasource.password=password

quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect


I'm also adding dependencies that I'm using :
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-oracle</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

Not sure is this relevant, but in IntellJ Database view I don't see table I'm using but it is visible in Dbeaver.

It seems to be similar to this: Spring 3 with Hibernate 6.2+ Application startup fail - mappingModelPart is null
Try to check if entities in your application are mapped correctly, in particular if there are some duplicated @Id or embedded identifiers, etc.
